# React Native how to use removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I replicate this code in React? I am new to react and I have not been able to get it, thank you very much in advance

```html
<progress id="bar" value="0" max="110"></progress>
<button onclick="increment()" id="increment">one time</button>
<button onclick="unlimited()" id="multiple">multiple</button>


<script>

var puntaje = document.getElementById("bar").value;
document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click",increment)

function increment (e)
{ e.target.removeEventListener(e.type,increment);
 document.getElementById("bar").value += 10;}

function unlimited (){document.getElementById("bar").value += 10}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use state to determine if the button has already been clicked once:

```
const component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [hasIncrementedOnce, setHasIncrementedOnce] =  React.useState(false);

  const increment = () => setValue((current) => current + 10);

  const incrementOnce = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (!hasIncrementedOnce) {
      increment();
      setHasIncrementedOnce(true);
    }
  }, [hasIncrementedOnce])

  return (
    <>
      <progress id="bar" value={value} max="110"></progress>
      <button onClick={incrementOnce} id="increment" disabled={hasIncrementedOnce}>one time</button>
      <button onClick={increment} id="multiple">multiple</button>
    </>
 );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!, I tried to test your code but it doesn't work for me, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, I also tried using render () but neither, could you put it in a spinnet? Excuse me but I'm a newbie to react.

Comment: @DiegoRodrigez You'll have to be more specific. This is a "function component" and works fine as described - https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bash-jpuc2

Comment: bro, you literally saved my life, thank you so much!